# How to convert datatable record into child custom Class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, datatable

I have two classes namely:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }
}
```

And I have two datatables with the following records

```
DataTable I (Parent Table)
ID     A     B
1      2     4
2      3     6
3      8     7
4      5     9

DataTable II (Child Table)
ParentID     C       D
2            4       10
4            9       7
```

If I want to convert the parent datatable to parent objects I user the following code:

```
IList<Parent> items = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
    new Parent
        {
            Id = row.Field<int>("Id"),
            A = row.Field<int>("A"),
            B = row.Field<int>("B"),
        }).ToList();
```

Obviously the parent objects with the Id of 2 and 4 has to be created as child objects However I have no idea how to do that.

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the Datatable already contain the joined result, so we could access `row.Field<int>("C")` if it has children, or are the children located in a different DataTable?

Comment: Yes, the children are located in different datatable.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> Obviously the parent objects with the Id of 2 and 4 has to be created as child objects

That is not really obvious. According to your layout, table II could have two rows with the same ParentId, which in your example could mean two people living together, while property A and B are address and telephone number while property C and D might mean birthday and favourite sport: two people living together with the same address and telephone number and different birthday and different favourite sport.

If you really wanted to express in your database that there would only one child with parent id 2 and one child with parent id 4, then your database wouldn't match the first normal database form and a different table layout that would prevent two people living together would be better.

Having said that, I guess that you want the following:

> Create a list from all children from table II and add all parents who don't have a child in table II. Properties A and B from the children should be taken from table I where Id equals ParentId.

- Create a dictionary with the parents from I
- Create a sequence with the children from II, use the dictionary to easily find the values for properties A and B
- Take all parents from I that don't have a child in II
- concat the children and the last parent list

.

```
var parentDictionary = AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(p => p.Id);
Ienumerable<Parent> children = II.asEnumerable()
    .Where( c => parentDictionary.Keys.Contains(c.ParentId))
    .Select(c => new Child()
        {
            A = parentDictionary[c.Id].A,
            B = parentDictionary[c.Id].B,
            C = c.C,
            D = c.D
         })
    .Cast<Parent>();

IEnumerable<Parent> parentsWithoutChildren = I.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(p => !II.AsEnumerable().Contains(p.Id));

IEnumerable<Parent> requestedPersons = parentsWithoutChildren
    .Concat(children);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that reads the DataTable which holds the child object information (I called it `childDataTable` in my code example) and creates either and instance of `Parent` or `Child`:

```
private Parent CreateObjectInstance(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        int parentId = dataRow.Field<int>("Id");
        var childRow = childDataTable.AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Field<int>("ParentID") == parentId);

        if (childRow != null)
            return new Child
            {
                Id = parentId ,
                A = dataRow.Field<int>("A"),
                B = dataRow.Field<int>("B"),
                C = childRow.Field<int>("C"),
                D = childRow.Field<int>("D")
            };
        else
            return new Parent
            {
                Id = parentId ,
                A = dataRow.Field<int>("A"),
                B = dataRow.Field<int>("B")
            };
    }
```

Then, in your LINQ-statement just call that function in the `Select` method:

```
var items = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(CreateObjectInstance).ToList();
```

This will return you a mixed list with `Parent` and `Child` objects in it